# Displaying JLabel based on combobox option

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlabel, mouselistener

How do I display a JLabel based on a combobox option. When I run the code all the JLabels are displayed straight away.

```
combo1.addActionListener(this);
panel.add(combo1);
panel.add(img1);
panel.add(img2);
panel.add(img3);

frame.add(panel);

    img1.setText("<html> Image : <a href=\"\">Image1/</a></html>");   
    img2.setText("<html> Image : <a href=\"\">Image2/</a></html>");
    img3.setText("<html> Image : <a href=\"\">Image3/</a></html>");

    img1.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    img2.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
    img3.setCursor(new Cursor(Cursor.HAND_CURSOR));
```

I'm using mouseListener to check which label is passed into the goWebsite() function, and then according to that it'll add a hyperlink to the label.

```
private void goWebsite(final JLabel website) {
        website.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                if(website == img1){
                try {
                    Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_2dxp9ORKKAM/TBZpViy7O1I/AAAAAAAABGY/zitq3ZLA8K4/s1600/red.png"));
                } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException ex) {
                    //It looks like there's a problem
                }
            }
                if(website == img2){
                    try {
                        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://www.pratikbagaria.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/04/BlueGreenPink.jpg"));
                    } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException ex) {
                        //It looks like there's a problem
                    }
                }
                if(website == img3){
                    try {
                        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://i.imgur.com/9OPnZNk.png"));
                    } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException ex) {
                        //It looks like there's a problem
                    }
                }
                if(website == img4){
                    try {
                        Desktop.getDesktop().browse(new URI("http://www.solidbackgrounds.com/images/three/2048x2048/2048x2048-fluorescent-orange-fluorescent-pink-fluorescent-yellow-three-color-background.jpg"));
                    } catch (URISyntaxException | IOException ex) {
                        //It looks like there's a problem
                    }
                }
```

The actionPerformed checks which option from the combobox the user has selected and then passes the right img JLabel into the goWebsite() function.

```
@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String color1 = (String)combo1.getSelectedItem();
        // Possibly check if either color is 'null' here
        if (color1.equals("red") )
        {

            goWebsite(img1);
        }
        if (color1.equals("blue") )
        {

            goWebsite(img2);
        }
        if (color1.equals("green") )
        {

            goWebsite(img3);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding a `ItemListener` to the `JComboBox`, when `itemStateChanged` is called, check that the `ItemEvent#getStateChanged` equals `ItemEvent.SELECTED`.

Check what is selected in the combo box (or use `ItemEvent#ItemSelected`) and either update a single `JLabel` with the information you want OR make the current label associated with the selected item visible by using `JLabel#setVisible(true)`, but also make sure you hide the others

For example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class ComboBoxUpdate {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new ComboBoxUpdate();
    }

    public ComboBoxUpdate() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JComboBox comboBox;
        private JLabel option1;
        private JLabel option2;
        private JLabel option3;

        public TestPane() {
            comboBox = new JComboBox(new String[]{"Choice 1", "Choice 2", "Choice 3"});
            option1 = new JLabel("Bananas");
            option2 = new JLabel("Appels");
            option3 = new JLabel("Grapes");
            option1.setVisible(false);
            option2.setVisible(false);
            option3.setVisible(false);

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            add(comboBox, gbc);
            add(option1, gbc);
            add(option2, gbc);
            add(option3, gbc);

            comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
                @Override
                public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
                    switch (e.getStateChange()) {
                        case ItemEvent.SELECTED:
                            Object value = comboBox.getSelectedItem();
                            option1.setVisible(false);
                            option2.setVisible(false);
                            option3.setVisible(false);
                            if ("Choice 1".equals(value)) {
                                option1.setVisible(true);
                            } else if ("Choice 2".equals(value)) {
                                option2.setVisible(true);
                            } else if ("Choice 3".equals(value)) {
                                option3.setVisible(true);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });

            comboBox.setSelectedItem(null);
        }
    }
}
```